# How does $\log_2 \epsilon^{-n}$ become $n\log_2(1/\epsilon)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The following is an equation from [this paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Edga/papers/cuckoo-conext2014.pdf) (Section 2.2) on something called Cuckoo filters. In the paper he does a what seems to be a simple rewriting: $$\log_2 \epsilon^{-n} = n\log_2(1/\epsilon)$$
However, when I try to do the same (i.e. going from left to right on the above equation) I keep ending up with $-n\log_2(\epsilon)$. How does he do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He does it as follows

$\log_2\epsilon^{-n}$=$\log_2({\frac{1}{\epsilon}})^n$=$n\log_2({\frac{1}{\epsilon}})$

Comment: as simple as that. thnx.

Comment: @GoldenRetriever If my answer helped you please accept it :-)

Comment: I don't understand why people don't accept legit answers. :/

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari because there is a time limit which has to be exceeded before I can do that. Now you understand :)

Comment: @Golden oh, didn't know about it.